# Is my proof correct that $a < b \implies S(a) \leq b$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, logic, proof-writing, peano-axioms

**Proof 1.1: $a < b \iff b = a + d$ for some positive natural number $d$**

First we prove that $a < b \implies b = a + d$ for positive $d$. We will prove it by contradiction. Suppose that $d$ is not positive, i.e. $d=0$. Then $b = a + 0 = a$. This is a contradiction, since $a < b \implies a \neq b$ by definition. Therefore $d$ must be positive.

Next we prove that $b = a + d \implies a < b$ for positive $d$. We already have $b = a + d \implies a \leq b$ by definition, but to show that it also implies $a < b$, it suffices to show that $a \neq b$. We can prove this by contradiction. Suppose $a = b$. Then $b = a = a + d$, or $a + 0 = a + d$ by additive identity, or $0 = d$ by cancellation law. However, this is a contradiction, since $d$ must be positive. Therefore $a \neq b$.

**Proof 1.2: $a < b \iff S(a) \leq b$**

First we prove that $a < b \implies S(a) \leq b$. By proof **1.1** we have $b = a + d$ for some positive $d$. Since $d \neq 0$ we can write $S(k) = d$ for some $k$ without violating Peano's 3rd axiom.

\begin{align}
b &= a + d \\
  &= a + S(k) \tag{substitution} \\
  &= S(a + k) \tag{definition of addition} \\
  &= S(a) + k \tag{definition of addition} \\
\end{align}

Next we prove that $S(a) \leq b \implies a < b$. We have $b = S(a) + d$ for some $d$. By definition of addition, $b = S(a+d) = a + S(d)$. By Peano's 3rd axiom, $S(d) \neq 0$, which means $S(d)$ is positive. By proof **1.1** this implies $a < b$.

Comment: I understand you're working with the Peano axioms .. but what definition(s) do you have with regard to $<$ and $\le$?

Comment: $a \leq b$ means $b = a + d$ for some $d$. $a < b$ means $a \leq b$ and $a \neq b$

Comment: OK, thanks.  Now, do you need a more formal way to express that '$d$ is positive'?  E.g. $0 < d$?  But then: when in 1.1 you show that $d \not = 0$, why would it be true that $0 < d$? Did you already prove that $\forall x (x \not = 0 \rightarrow 0 < x)$? I also note you refer to a cancellation law .. can you assume that's already proven as well? And another one: you say that if $d \not = 0$, then $d = s(k)$ for some $k$: is that another lemma you can use? It might be good to spell out all the Lemma's you are allowed to use ...

Comment: Oh, one more: the typical Peano axiom for addition says that $a+s(b)=s(a+b)$ ... not that $s(a) + b = s(a+b)$, so again you'd need to have that as a Lemma when you use this in Proof 1.2

Comment: @Bram28 I forgot to mention but I've already proven a bunch of stuff about addition so those two are equivalent. Positive I define as not zero.

Comment: OK, if you have all the necessary lemma's already proven then this certainly looks like a good proof!

Comment: @Bram28 Reading your comment again -- I don't see where I say $0 < d$?

Comment: Well, I asked what you meant by '$d$ is positive', and suggested $0<d$. But you're right; you could just say $d \not = 0$

Comment: $0<d$ I guess I can prove by showing if $d\neq 0$ then $d=0+m=m$ with $m\neq 0$ therefore by 1.1 we have $0<d$?

Comment: Not by 1.1, but by definition of $<$: we know $0+d=d$ so $0 \le d$, and since $0 \not = d$ by definition of $<$: $0<d$

Comment: Oh derp, of course, thanks

Comment: Sure!  Now, did you ever prove: $\forall x (x \not = 0 \rightarrow \exists y \ x = s(y)$?

Comment: @Bram28 Is that something I have to prove? Seems like a natural and direct consequence. If you know $x \neq 0$ then we can write $S(y) = x$ for some $y$ without violating Peano's 3rd axiom. Otherwise: No I have not proven that

Comment: Sure, all kinds of things are true without violating Peano's axioms, but that is not the same as *deriving* it from Peano's axioms. For example, the statement $Q$ does not violate the statement $P$, but it clearly does not follow from it. So yes, this is something you need to prove.

Comment: I summed up our discussion in an Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of comments:

First: With these kinds of elementary results, the key is to spell out *exactly* what axioms you have, and any theorems you can use that you already have proven from those axioms. It looks like you're working with Peano arithmetic,  I assume you have the following axioms:

$\forall x \ s(x) \not = 0$

$\forall x \forall y (s(x) = s(y) \rightarrow x = y)$

$\forall x \ x+0=x$

$\forall x \forall y \ x + s(y) = s(x+y)$

plus induction scheme

You also use the following definitions:

$\forall x \forall y (x \le y \leftrightarrow \exists z \ y = x + z)$

$\forall x \forall y (x < y \leftrightarrow (x \le y \land x \not = y))$

Your proof also needs the following lemma's:

$\forall x \forall y \ s(x) + y = s(x+y)$ (which requires induction to be proven)

$\forall x \forall y \forall z (x + z = y+z \rightarrow x = y)$ (also requires induction)

Second: you'll want to be more clear on what you mean by '$d$ is positive' ... I suggest $0 < d$

Third: In proof 1.2 you write:

> Since $d \neq 0$ we can write $S(k) = d$ for some $k$ without violating Peano's 3rd axiom.

That's not a valid step in a proof. You can't say: "this is true, because it doesn't violate any of the axioms".  For example, if your axiom is $P$, you can't say: "Hey, $Q$ doesn't violate $P$, so $Q$ is true".

So, you'll need to actually *prove* the following lemma:

$\forall x (x \not = 0 \rightarrow \exists y \ x = s(y))$

(Hint: requires induction)

Comment: Very helpful to know, thank you

Comment: (And yes I am using those axioms/lemmas/definitions/etc -- I prove a lot of those in other posts, forgot to mention what I am assuming/using in full). I don't really know the difference between definition, lemma, proposition, axiom, etc though. Maybe I'll make that a new q

Comment: @user525966 Glad I could help! :)